# What is the right way to create custom query in spring-data-jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am facing an issue where when I run my spring boot application with my custom query method, I am getting an exception.

My repository class is below

```
public interface ProductRepository extends Repository<Product,Integer> {

@Query(name = "SELECT p.rate FROM Product p WHERE p.id=:id")
public Optional<String> findRateById(@Param("id") int id);

@Modifying
@Query(name = "UPDATE Product p set p.productName=:productName WHERE p.id=:id")
public int updateProductNameById(@Param("id") int id,@Param("productName") String 
productName);

}
```

And the exception that I'm getting

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract int com.spring.data.jpa.repository.ProductRepository.updateProductNameById(int,java.lang.String)! No property updateProductNameById found for type Product!
```

Comment: package com.spring.data.jpa.repository;
    import com.spring.data.jpa.entity.Product;
    import com.spring.data.jpa.exception.ProductNotFoundException;  
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
    import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;
    import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
    import java.util.*;

Comment: Instead of using the `name` parameter, you should be using `value` parameter in the `@Query`. i.e. `@Query(value = "UPDATE Product p set p.productName=:productName WHERE p.id=:id")` or `@Query("UPDATE Product p set p.productName=:productName WHERE p.id=:id")`

Comment: I beleive Ashish is right I tried @Modifying
    @Query("update Product p set p.category=:cat where p.id=:id")
    int updateCateById(@Param("cat") String cat, @Param("id") Integer id); and it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

The name property within the @Query annotation determines the use of a NamedQuery. 
If you want to use Named Query than you should use the @NamedQuery annotation in your entity.

```
@Entity
@Table
@NamedQuery(name="updateProduct", query="UPDATE PRODUCT ....")
public class Product
```

You can read more about it here [JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)

If you don't want to use namedquery than, just remove the name property inside the @Query annotation.

Comment: Thanks buddy, My mistake was i added "name" parameter in @Query annotation, for that reason it was not working, I removed it now everything is ok.